# How do I exit a Clojure walk postwalk on a nested maps on the first true predicate match?

Tags: clojure

I am using `clojure.walk/postwalk` to compare a predicate to every map in a nested collection and want to exit with true on the first `true`. How would I do that? I am ok with it walking the whole data structure and then returning true if there is a `true` match.

As a corollary question, I guess the same question could apply to when one performs a `map` as opposed to a `postwalk`.

UPDATE: this was truly a tired/lazy question; I should have provided a code example. That said, I'm leaving it up in case anyone is currently formulating an answer to my half-baked question. The only thing that is worse than asking one is taking it down after someone has been kind enough to start helping. I will be quite content if no one answers, if they request a better question, or if they just give me suggestions of what to research.

Comment: If the only result you want is `true` or `false`, it sounds like you don't want a `postwalk` at all. You want to write a recursive function that consumes one of your structures and produces a boolean as a result. Then you can short-circuit if you find the result in one branch.

Comment: That sounds right... I'll look into that now.

Comment: Once the predicate is true, you can throw an exception from within the walk. If the surrounding code catches that exception, it means the predicate was true somewhere. This approach is certainly unconventional but it could work.

Answer (score 3):

a bit different way to do it, also employing `tree-seq`:

```
(defn find-deep [pred data not-found]
  (->> data
       (tree-seq coll? seq)
       (some #(when (pred %) [%]))
       ((fnil first [not-found]))))

user> (find-deep #(= (:c %) 30) [{:a 10 :b [{:c 20 :d {:c 30}}]}] ::none)
;;=> {:c 30}

user> (find-deep #(= (:c %) 40) [{:a 10 :b [{:c 20 :d {:c 30}}]}] ::none)
;;=> :user/none
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this function I call `walk-seq`. It returns a lazy depth-first sequence over a data structure which you can then `seek` against to find the first match. I find it to be preferable here because it doesn't require callbacks and exceptions to exit early like `clojure.walk/postwalk` would.

```clj
(defn walk-seq 
  "Returns a lazy depth-first sequence of all forms within a data structure."
  [form]
  (tree-seq coll? seq form))

(defn seek
  "Find the first element in the collection that matches pred,
   else returns not-found. Note that using seek can lead to
   poor performance and you should always use indexed data
   structures instead of multiple seeks over the same data."
  ([pred coll]
   (seek pred coll nil))
  ([pred coll not-found]
   (reduce (fn [nf x] (if (pred x) (reduced x) nf)) not-found coll)))
```

Usage of `walk-seq`:

```clj
(walk-seq {:a [{:b -1} {:b 1}] :b 2})
=>
({:a [{:b -1} {:b 1}], :b 2}
 [:a [{:b -1} {:b 1}]]
 :a
 [{:b -1} {:b 1}]
 {:b -1}
 [:b -1]
 :b
 -1
 {:b 1}
 [:b 1]
 :b
 1
 [:b 2]
 :b
 2)
```

Combining the two:

```clj
(seek (every-pred number? pos?) (walk-seq {:a [{:b -1} {:b 1}] :b 2}))
=>
1
```

Comment: I believe `coll?` (from the standard library) can be used instead of `branch?`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer to use `coll?`. I had vague memories of some case that led me to use `seqable?` instead but I can't find it now - perhaps it was specific to custom data types in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using postwalk by throwing an exception once the predicate is true as I suggested in the comment. This approach is unconventional but concise and lets us reuse the logic of `postwalk` for walking the datastructure:

```
(defn walk-some [pred data]
  (try
    (clojure.walk/postwalk
     #(if (pred %)
        (throw (ex-info "Found" {:data %}))
        %)
     data)
    false
    (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
      true)))

(walk-some #(and (number? %) (odd? %)) {:a [[9] 3]})
;; => true

(walk-some #(and (number? %) (even? %)) {:a [[9] 3]})
;; => false
```

Using exceptions for control flow is rarely needed but occasionally it useful to deviate a bit from convention. You may want to define a *custom exception type* for improved robustness in case your predicate can throw objects of type `ExceptionInfo`.